# What's the explanation for Kohler's rule?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, electrical-resistance

In a metal, the increase of resistivity ($\Delta\rho$) due to an applied magnetic field follows a functional form of the parameter $\rho_0/B$ (residual resistivity divided by magnetic field) i.e.

$$(\Delta\rho)/(\rho_0) = F(\rho_0/B)$$

that is known as the [Kohler's rule](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=kohler+rule+wiki).

What is the physical explanation of this rule?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea behind Kohler's rule is that magnetoresistance (MR) is proportional to how many cyclotron orbits the quasiparticle (electron or hole) can make before scattering. When there is more scattering (bigger $\rho_0$), the fewer cyclotron orbits can be completed, and the MR is accordingly reduced. The parameter B/$\rho_0$ can be thought of as a reduced magnetic field - bigger B means more cyclotron orbits can be completed, bigger $\rho_0$ means fewer cyclotron orbits can be completed.

Since MR only depends on how many cyclotron orbits are completed, it must be a universal function of B/$\rho_0$, namely $\Delta\rho/\rho_0 = F(B/\rho_0)$.